# How to run HTML script for two tabels

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the JavaScript code below to sort the date column in an HTML table, this works fine but I would like to apply the script to another table. I have tried using a different table id for the second table and adding this to the variable and also creating another variable to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
    <html>





    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        table {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

            table th {
                background-color: #B8DBFD;
                color: #333;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            table th, table td {
                padding: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }

            table, table table td {
                border: 0px solid #ccc;
            }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>




    <h1>Top Freezer</h1>
    <p>
        <button class="sort-season sort-season--start">Sort 
    Date</button>
    </p>
    <table id="results" width="360" border="1">

        <tbody>



            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>StoredDate</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var topstock in Model.TopModels)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@topstock.Description</td>
                    <td>@topstock.Quantity</td>
                    <td>@topstock.StoredDate</td>

                </tr>
            }



        </tbody>
    </table>



    <h2>Bottom Freezer</h2>

    
    <table id="result" width="360" border="1">
        <tbody>



            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>StoredDate</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var bottomstock in Model.BottomModels)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@bottomstock.Description</td>
                    <td>@bottomstock.Quantity</td>
                    <td>@bottomstock.StoredDate</td>

                </tr>
            }



        </tbody>
    </table>
   </body>
   </html>

 

    <script>
        function convertDate(d) {
            var p = d.split("/");
            return +(p[2] + p[1] + p[0]);
        }

        function sortByDate(direction) {
            var tbody = document.querySelector("#results tbody");
            
            // get trs as array for ease of use
            var rows = [].slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr"));

            if (direction === 'asc') {
                document.querySelector(".sort-season").classList.remove('sort-season--start');
                document.querySelector(".sort-season").classList.add('sort-season--end');

                rows.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return (
                        convertDate(b.cells[2].innerHTML) -
                        convertDate(a.cells[2].innerHTML)
                    );
                });
            } else {
                document.querySelector(".sort-season").classList.add('sort-season--start');
                document.querySelector(".sort-season").classList.remove('sort-season--end');

                rows.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return (
                        convertDate(a.cells[2].innerHTML) -
                        convertDate(b.cells[2].innerHTML)
                    );
                });
            }

            rows.forEach(function (v) {
                tbody.appendChild(v);
            });
        }

        document.querySelector(".sort-season").addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (document.querySelector(".sort-season").classList.contains('sort-season--start')) {
                document.querySelector(".sort-season").innerText = "Sort Date";

                sortByDate('asc');
            } else {
                document.querySelector(".sort-season").innerText = "Sort Date";

                sortByDate('desc');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified the code a little using arrow functions and made the class name for the button tied into the direction better. I gave the sortable tables a classname to target them.

```js
function convertDate(d) {
  var p = d.split("/");
  let v =  +(p[2] + p[1] + p[0]);
  return v
}

document.querySelector(".sort-season").addEventListener("click", e => {
  let dir = e.target.classList.contains('sorting-asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
  e.target.classList.remove("sorting-asc", "sorting-desc");
  e.target.classList.add(`sorting-${dir}`);
  e.target.querySelector('span').innerHTML = (dir == 'asc' ? "&#x25B2;" : "&#x25BC;");
  sortByDate(dir); // send to your sort function the reference element that was clicked
});

function sortByDate(direction) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".sortable-table tbody").forEach(tbody => {
    let rows = [].slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr"));
    
    if (direction === 'asc') {
      rows.sort((a, b) =>
          convertDate(b.cells[2].innerHTML) -
          convertDate(a.cells[2].innerHTML)
        );
    } else {
      rows.sort((a, b) =>
          convertDate(a.cells[2].innerHTML) -
          convertDate(b.cells[2].innerHTML)
        );
    }
    rows.forEach((v) => tbody.appendChild(v));
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #fff;
}

table th {
  background-color: #B8DBFD;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

table,
table table td {
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h1>Top Freezer</h1>
<p>
  <button class="sort-season sorting-asc">Sort 
    Date <span>&#x25BC;</span></button>
</p>
<table id="results" class='sortable-table' width="360" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>StoredDate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>@topstock.Description</td>
      <td>@topstock.Quantity</td>
      <td>2022/10/05</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@topstock.Description</td>
      <td>@topstock.Quantity</td>
      <td>2021/06/05</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Bottom Freezer</h2>
<table id="result" class='sortable-table' width="360" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>StoredDate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>@topstock.Description</td>
      <td>@topstock.Quantity</td>
      <td>2022/12/05</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@topstock.Description</td>
      <td>@topstock.Quantity</td>
      <td>2023/12/05</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All sounds logical but I have tried the suggested code but it doesn't work. I will have another look tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Go ahead and add the HTML to your question - 2 tables. I can add that to my answer to make it a working snippet

Comment: Thank you. I have added the code, although the data is coming from a DB but the tables are pretty simple.

Comment: Updated my answer. Different solution

Comment: That's awesome, works a treat. Thank you very much for taking the time to help.